# Push registration and receiver methods static library

Tags: ios

I need to create a static library in Objective-C that will have Push registration and receiver methods in it. My library will be replicating the Appdelegate functionality and so minimizes coding effort in App. Is it possible to implement push notification inside a static library?

eg:- UrbarnAirship and Mixpanel

Plz share the code reference or tutorials

Answer (score 0):

No Push notification requires APNS certificate that is not possible in static library .

Comment: is there any other alternate solution to implement the functionality